# proxychains doesn't work

Tags: 10.04, proxy

I configured `proxychains` like this:

```
strict_chain

proxy_dns

tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

[ProxyList]
http    ip1.myproxyserver.org      443     myuser   mypass
```

but when I try to use it with the `proxychains wget -qO/dev/null http://google.com` it gives this:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| google.com 
|DNS-response|: google.com is not exist
```

by removing the `proxy_dns` it gives this (!!):

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
```

and doesn't work at all.

**What is the problem?**